# Extensions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ (Hilton & Stammbach III.1.2)

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Question is to compute $E(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})$ i.e., equivalence classes of 
extensions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by $\mathbb{Z}$

By an extension of $A$ by $B$ i mean an $R$ module $E$ such that  $B\rightarrow E\rightarrow A$ is an exact sequence.

I say $B\rightarrow E_1\rightarrow A$ and $B\rightarrow E_2\rightarrow A$ are equivalent if there exists a homomorphism $\zeta : E_1\rightarrow E_2$ such that the following diagram commutes

\begin{matrix}
B&\to&E_1&\to&A\\
\|&&\;\;\downarrow f&&\|\\
B&\to&E_2&\to&A
\end{matrix}

Now First question is to show that :

$$\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow {\mu} \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\epsilon} \mathbb{Z}_3 ~\text{and }~ \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow {\mu'} \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\epsilon'} \mathbb{Z}_3 $$ where $\mu=\mu'$ is multiplication by $3$, $\epsilon(1)=1 (\mod 3)$ and $\epsilon'(1)=2 (\mod 3)$  are not equivalent.

Second Question is (use above idea) to compute $E(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})$...

I have solved first exercise and with that i realized that there are atleast $p-1$ non equivalent extensions with $\mu$ being multiplication by $p$ and $\epsilon_i=i\mod p$ for $1\leq i\leq  p-1$.

And then I have split extension $$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$$

So i have $p$ extensions now..

I am not able to prove there are no other extensions which are not equivalent to any of this..

Please help me to see this....

If any one can make that commutative diagram using latex i will be so thankful.. I tried to google for drawing commutative diagrams but i am not able to do as of now..

Thank you.

This is an exercise in Hilton & Stammbach's **A Course in Homological algebra** chapter $3$, Exercise $1.2$

Comment: Do you really mean $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or do you mean $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg :  If you see $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as p-adic integers then i mean $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$... Should i change it??

Comment: @Olivier : Thank you :)

Comment: No problem! ${}$

Comment: Are you missing the split extension?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Split extension.. I have not heard of such (I am just a beginner).. If split extension mean $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ then i think i should have written that also...

Comment: Yes Yes... As i have said in the question i proved that $\epsilon,\epsilon'$ are not equivalent in case of $e(1)=1\mod 3$ and $\epsilon'=2\mod 3$.. Same approach applies to prime $p$ also... I thought of explaining that also in the question but as that is better seen in commutative diagrams and i am not familiar with drawing commutative diagrams i have not included it...

Comment: If $\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow {\mu} E\xrightarrow{\epsilon} \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a short exact sequence, then it shouldn't be too difficult to show that $E$ must be generated by $\mu(1)$ and any element $z$ with the property that $\epsilon(z)=\overline{1}$. Thus $E$ is generated by two elements. The structure theory of f.g. abelian groups then implies that $E$ is either cyclic or a direct sum of two cyclic groups. Can you pick it up from there?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : i have not mentioned in the question but i have done some thing similar... I have $E/ker(\epsilon)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ and as $ker(\epsilon)=\mu(\mathbb{Z})$ i have $E/\mu(\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$... But i am afraid to say that this implies $E$ is generated by elements you have described... :O

Comment: Ok. Let $e$ be an arbitrary element of $E$. Then $\epsilon(e)$ is some element of $\Bbb{Z}_p$. So there is an integer $m, 0\le m<p, $ such that $\epsilon(e)=\overline{m}=\epsilon(mz)$. This implies that $e-mz$ is in the kernel of $\epsilon$...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Oh Yes Yes.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\def\ZZ{\mathbb Z}0\to\ZZ\xrightarrow{f}E\xrightarrow{g}\ZZ_p\to0$ is a non-split extension.

If $E$ has non-zero torsion, then that torsion clearly does not intersect the image of $f$, and therefore is mapped injectively into $\ZZ_p$. You can easily construct, then, a map $\ZZ_p\to E$ which is a section to $g$: this contradicts non-splitness.

It follows that $E$ is torsion free. As Jyrki observes, $E$ is either cyclic or a direct sum of two cyclic groups. It it were a direct sum of two cyclic groups, its quotient by the image of $f$ would be infinite. It follows that $E$ is isomorphic to $\ZZ$. Now there are exactly $p-1$ surjective homomorphisms from $\ZZ$ to $\ZZ_p$, etc.

Comment: I am sorry, i did not understand **If it were a direct sum of two cyclic groups, its quotient by the image of f would be infinite**...

Comment: If it were the direct sum of two infinite cyclic groups, its rank would be two. The quotient of an abelian group of rank two by a subgroup of rank one has rank one and is, in particular, infinite.

Comment: Yes Yes.. I got that... I understand that one group  has to be infinite in the decomposition... I was thinking one could be infinite and other could be finite cyclic group... group generated by $\mu(1)$ can not be finite because then we would end up in a module having torsion element but i am not sure about other part..

Comment: Well, the whole point of my second pararaph is to check that if the extension is not split, then the group $E$ does not have torsion!

Comment: Sorry to test your patience but i did not get your comment...

Comment: The second paragraph in my answer proves that $E$ does not have torsion. It follows that $E$ cannot be the direct sum of an infinite cyclic group and a (non-trivial) finite cyclic group, since any such direct sum has non-zero torsion.

Comment: oh no, Suppose $E=M\oplus N$ where $N$ is finite cyclic group, I will consider $(0,1)$.. This would be a torsion element... Am i correct?

Comment: Of course. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know why it took so much time for me to realize this... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is supposed to be homological algebra, let's compute $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z})$.

We have the exact sequence $0\to \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\cdot p}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\to 0$.  Applying $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p,-)$, we see that $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z})\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is exact.  But $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p)=\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}/p}(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p) = 0$ ($\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a projective module over itself), so $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p$, i.e. there are exactly $p$ inequivalent extensions.

Comment: This is, indeed, how this would get done with the theory in place. Unfortunately at this point in the development of the theory in Hilton-Stammbach the $E(A,B)$ has not been identified as a derived functor of Hom. Of course, your answer may/will appeal to people who have seen a bit more.

Comment: As this idea is not yet introduced i am not supposed to use this.. Thank you :)